# ng-repeat double rendered after array is updated

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a problem whereby my ng-repeat renders are doubled after the first array update.

The problem happens when you first removed an object from the array, the ng-repeat messed up the rendering and doubled rendered. Note that when you try to delete john 0, the number of divs in the column doubled from 20 to 39

[Buggy Demo](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2686709/buggy/index.html)

I am currently using a directive to present the information.

When I removed the directive that is responsible for displaying the information, and just present the information, as well as triggering the click in the ng-repeat itself, it works properly (number of elements in the column became 19)

[This is the plunkr containing the code](http://plnkr.co/edit/KmZGK2), but I am unable to replicate it on plunkr

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: inspect live html in dropbox version...has double the number of DIV in column. Different in plunker

Comment: Yes I see that. Thank you for highlighting it. Did some more investigations. 

The array to be repeated became shorter after a delete call, which is correct. The changes are reflected correctly in the plunker. However, my divs in the columns are doubled in the dropbox version.

This is the part which I do not understand. Both versions are processing the ng-repeat with the same things, but the code doesn't work outside plunker.

Comment: It is a bug with angularjs. Work around is to use the directive as a child of the ng-repeat and not make element itself the directive.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2151

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem.

It was a bug with angularjs.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2151

Updating your angularjs version to 1.2.4 will solve the issue.

The work around is to use the directive as a child of the ng-repeat and not the ng-repeat element itself.